# Simple Increment in assembler

Tags: c, assembly

I'm stuck with this. I'm self studying assenbler and translating some basics instructions. But i can't with this one.

Can anyone help me, please?

```
int
secuencia ( int n, EXPRESION * * o )
{
  int a, i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){

    a = evaluarExpresion( *o );

    // Im trying to do this: o++;
  __asm {
      mov eax,dword ptr [o] 
      mov ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
      inc [ecx]  
    }
  }
  return a ;
}
```

I wrote the inside for and works, but still don't know how to increment O

```
int
secuencia ( int n, EXPRESION * * o )
{
  int a, i;
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){

      __asm {

            mov eax,dword ptr [o] 
            mov ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
        push ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            push ecx

            call evaluarExpresion
        mov esp, ebp

        pop ebp

        mov a, eax
      }

    o++;
  }
  return a ;
}
```

Comment: The console doesn't do nothing (blank). When I change all the __asm {...} to o++ it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov esi, o
add esi, 4 //increment is here
```

Line1 : We move your o pointer to the esi register.
Line2: We increment your o pointer

or

```
mov eax, o
mov esi, [eax]
add esi, 4
```

I don't understand perfectly what you are trying to do but I hope it helped!

Comment: Hi toto,

I try that:

   call evaluarExpresion

  mov esi, [o]
  add esi, 4 //increment is here

  
  mov esp, ebp

But doesn't work. Or do I need to put it in another place?

Comment: Of course! Don't use INC, pointers are 4 bytes (in 32-bit assembly language...)

Comment: Hi Toto, and thanks again.

What I need to do is that inside assembler, replace the o++ instruction.

I need to get a pointer to o, and modify the instruction within that pointer to add 4 (so it can pass to next element). I try both of your recommendations but doesn't work. What is more strange is that just leaving o++ outside the asm (of course is C) it works. So It must be a translating issue. I don't know if I explain myself. Thank  you very much for your help.

Comment: Your solution works!!! but not on this compiler :(
Still, thank you very much! and check below, that goes for you also!

Comment: I think, in the first example, you must add `mov o, esi` to save the value back to the `o` variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

Either:

- move the value of `o` from memory into a register (eax, for example)
- increment the register
- move the value from the register back to memory

or

- increment the value stored in memory directly

Try to use both methods.

Comment: I'd give some code but I've never used MASM syntax (or whatever it is you're using).

Comment: Hi Artelius, I know that I need to do the second one, But i really don't know how. I'm working for a few hours... but nothing, can you please code-explain me? I also try with lea eax, o but doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: Try `inc dword ptr o` or `inc dword ptr [o]`. If this succeeds, good, but I suggest for practice you also try to move `o` into a register, increment the register, and move the register into memory again.

Comment: I pass the values to the registries but still have the problem. I edit the question, could you please check it out? thanks!

Comment: I follow your recomendation and read about it. I'm using MASM and what  I want to do is not possible (at least not in a easy way).

So I just incresea the value directly following the advice from toto: add o, 4 and it solves the problem. Thank you! (Do you want a google wave invitation as a way to say thanks?)

Comment: That would be nice! I shall send you an email.